# Hi, someone can help me with some django views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I hope someone can solve this problem. My goal is to take the last hour posts and insert them in a dictionary with all the info (author, title, text and published date). At the end I want to dumps it in an html file. This is my code:

views.py

```
@superuser_only
def PostUltimaOra(request):
    post_detail = {}
    dt = now()
    PostsLastHour = Post.objects.filter(published_date__range=(dt-timedelta(hours=1), dt))
    for each in PostsLastHour:
        post_detail = {
            'author': each.author,
            'title': each.title,
            'text': each.text,
            'published_date': each.published_date,
        }
    dj = json.dump(post_detail)
    return render(request, 'blog/numeroposts.html', {'dj': dj})
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     text = models.TextField()
     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


     def publish(self):
         self.published_date = timezone.now()
         self.save()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
     <h1>{{ 'Posts per utente:' }}</h1>
     {% for k, v in numero.items %}
         {{ 'L utente con id n° '}} {{ k }} {{ ' ha pubblicato '}}  {{ v }} {{ ' posts' }}
         <p>{{ ''|linebreaksbr }}</p>
     {% endfor %}
     <h2>{{ 'I post pubblicati nell utlima ora sono questi: ' }} {{ dj }}</h2>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem is that in the template ther's nothing

Answer (score 0):

Oh... no need of doing all that and json'ing the QuerySet just pass QuerySet as context to template...

```
@superuser_only
def PostUltimaOra(request):
    post_detail = {}
    dt = now()
    PostsLastHour = Post.objects.filter(published_date__range=(dt-timedelta(hours=1), dt))
    
    return render(request, 'blog/numeroposts.html', {'dj': PostsLastHour})
```

and in template:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
     <h1>{{ 'Posts per utente:' }}</h1>
     {% for k in dj %}
         'L utente con id n°  {{ k.title }}   ha pubblicato   {{ k.author }}  posts
         <p>{{ ''|linebreaksbr }}</p>
     {% endfor %}
     <h2> I post pubblicati nell utlima ora sono questi:  {{ dj|length }}</h2>


{% endblock %}
```

something like this (i dont speak yours language)